# Running the app script by itself it give error and do not send files to cloudinary

Tags: javascript

What a am aiming to do here is.

1. when choosing files from my app in phone, it must then send them to cloudinary and get URLs and then save them with all other date in my google sheet.
   2 I cannot get it to work, in app sheet, it save my folder and file name from my phone in google at the moment.

I am not get the code to run, when run it in appscript it gives error "7:50:07 PM   Notice  Execution started
7:49:37 PM  Info    Cloudinary API error: Exception: Request failed for https://api.cloudinary.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"error":{"message":"Missing required parameter - file"}} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
7:50:08 PM  Notice  Execution completed"

my code

```
// Function to send files to Cloudinary and get new URLs
function uploadFileToCloudinary(fileUrl) {
  var CLOUD_NAME = "d23e4r5th"; // Add your Cloudinary cloud name here
  var cloudinaryURL = "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/" + CLOUD_NAME + "/upload";
  var apiKey = "123467896571973";
  var apiSecret = "C57at7h8jhghoJMVzlD5555";

  var formData = {
    file: fileUrl,
    upload_preset: "qdrgthuo1", // Optional, if you're using an upload preset
    api_key: apiKey,
    api_secret: apiSecret
  };

  var options = {
    method: "post",
    payload: formData
  };

  try {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(cloudinaryURL, options);
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

    // Log the API response for debugging
    Logger.log(jsonResponse);

    var newFileUrl = jsonResponse.secure_url;
    return newFileUrl;
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("Cloudinary API error: " + error);
    return null; // Return null in case of an error
  }
}

// Function to upload files regularly
function uploadFileRegularly() {
  // Replace the fileUrls array with the list of file URLs you want to upload
  var fileUrls = [
    "URL_OF_FILE_1",
    "URL_OF_FILE_2",
    "URL_OF_FILE_3",
    // Add more file URLs as needed
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < fileUrls.length; i++) {
    Logger.log("Uploading file from URL: " + fileUrls[i]); // Add this line for debugging
    var newFileUrl = uploadFileToCloudinary(fileUrls[i]);
    // Optionally, you can do something with the newFileUrl if needed
    Logger.log("Uploaded file URL: " + newFileUrl);
  }
}
```

I have done all I can think of